# How A/C board works on an air conditioner

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, relay

I have a question.

I got a Panasonic CU-C24GVK (24000 BTU Air conditioner), and the A/C board relay is burnt. If I'm not explaining myself, the A/C board is the thermostat itself, the board receive the 240V, and after some minutes it send a signal to a relay that connects those 240V to the outdoor unit's compressor, that board have the following diagram:

[image: A/C Board]

The question is, I want to know how this exactly works, because the relay that connects the 240V line with the COMP output is bad, so I cut the wire and connect the line directly to the COMP, so the compressor will be ON all the time, however, what is happening is that the compressor turns on, and after like 20 min, it turns off and never go back on again, it only turns on if I let it rest a while cutting the electrical supply to the thermostat. A technician told me that because of what I did, the run capacitor might be getting overheated, I ran a test, I waited for night, and as the outside temperature is lower, the compressor doesn't turn off.

But that have no sense to me, how a capacitor will get overheated for constant electrical supply if in a normal run it also have a constant supply unless the thermostat wants to shutdown the compressor? Can anyone explain that to me?

Comment: _"A technician told me that because of what I did, the run capacitor might be getting overheated"_ That would be a terrible design and difficult to pass any UL or CE certification, although not impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compressor is overheating,and the internal thermal cutout is tripping.After it cools the compressor runs again.

Comment: Okay, that have more sense, but then, why the compressor is overheating?, All my explaination gives some clue I didn't catch?

Comment: Because the motor is faulty? And that destroyed the relay?

Comment: Or possibly because there is water, air (nitrogen) or something else in the coolant loop.  Split units usually require evacuation of the lines after the internal unit is connected, if this is not done properly compressor failures are the normal outcome.